# What's the appropriate exception to throw in this case?

Tags: java, exception

```
public Item getItem(String name){
    if(someContainer.containsKey(name)) return someContainer.get(name);
    throw new /*...*/Exception("Item doesn't exist");
}
```

What kind of exception is appropriate to throw in this case? `IllegalArgumentException` doesn't feel quite right.

Comment: Why not just return `null` instead of throwing exception, like `map.get(key)` does if `key` doesn't exist in map.

Comment: @Pshemo Because I want to catch error early. If I have a container which should be able to hold `null`s, than I will return `null` if the key doesn't exist in the map. But often there are places in my app that shouldn't hold `null`, and if they do it's a sign of an error somewhere. So throwing exceptions in these cases allows me to catch these errors early. In your opinion is this correct use of exceptions?

Comment: A suitable exception could be the `NoSuchElementException` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).

Comment: If the only possible reason for a non-existing item is that the caller passes an invalid name, and passing an invalid name is a bug, then IllegalArgumentException seems appropriate. If non-existing names are normal and expected, and the caller doesn't know in advance if the name exists or not, then returning null, or an `Optional<Item>` is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create your own (how about `ItemNotFoundException`?)

It makes catching and reacting to it easier, too, because you can catch exactly that exception, and not an `IllegalArgumentException` that might be thrown somewhere else.

Comment: Odd that the standard library doesn't have an exception to suit this problem. BTW in your opinion is it better to throw an exception or return `null`?

Comment: @Prog: It depends. Exceptions should be used when something goes wrong. If you *expect* that `getItems` is called for non existing items, don't use an exception; if a item should exist when the class is used right, then use an Exception. E.g. a `List` contains elements at positions `0, 1, ..., size()-1` and therefore the class is not used in the right way, if you pass any other index to the `get` method (=> `IndexOutOfBoundsException`). In contrast to that, if you use a `Map` you don't expect it to contain values for all keys and therefore `get` doesn't throw an exception.